# How do I reduce the size of my logo on a packing slip that is taking up half of a page?

Tags: bigcommerce

I tried to delete the code %%GLOBAL_HeaderLogo%% on the packing_slip_print.html file but is removes all formatting.
Here is the entire code:

%%GLOBAL_HeaderLogo%%

%%GLOBAL_StoreName%% %%GLOBAL_PackingSlipTitle%%

%%GLOBAL_StoreAddressFormatted%%

%%LNG_BillTo%%

%%GLOBAL_BillingAddress%%

%%LNG_Phone%%: %%GLOBAL_BillingPhone%%

%%LNG_ShipTo%%

%%GLOBAL_ShippingAddress%%

%%LNG_Phone%%: %%GLOBAL_ShippingPhone%%

%%LNG_Order%%:

#%%GLOBAL_OrderId%%

%%LNG_ShipmentOrderDate%%:

%%GLOBAL_OrderDate%%

%%LNG_ShippingMethod%%:

%%GLOBAL_ShippingMethod%%

%%LNG_DateShipped%%:

%%GLOBAL_DateShipped%%

%%LNG_TrackingNumber%%:

%%GLOBAL_TrackingNo%%

%%LNG_ShippedItems%%

%%GLOBAL_ProductsTable%%

%%LNG_Quantity%%

%%LNG_Code%%

%%LNG_ProdName%%

%%LNG_ProdBin%%

%%LNG_Comments%%

%%GLOBAL_Comments%%

Answer (score 1):

The logo on your packing slip comes from the same place as the logo at the top of your website, so in order to change it, you should navigate in your Control Panel to Storefront>Logo. It should display in that page what the recommended image size is for your theme. For Cornerstone, it is 250 x 100px

If you need a larger image for your site's header, I would recommend adding the image in a banner or coding it into your theme. The "logo" settings are optimized for a specific image size that depends on the theme, and if you have a large image uploaded here it will not look good on your packing slips or printable invoices.